# Silverlight object in aspx page - not occupying full page space

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, silverlight, iis

In my aspx page, i am creating two . In the first one, am using aspx menu and in second panel, adding the Silverlight object. But i can see that at the bottom of browser, there is an Empty space of height 100px(approx). Why this space getting added? How to remove that space?

Thanx in advance.

Sample code:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlMenu" runat="server">
        <table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td>                                             
                    <img id="imgLogo" alt="no image" style="float:left;display:none;height:20px; width:90px;"  />                        
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img src="sample.png" alt="no image" style="float: right" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Code to add menu
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel ID="silverlightControlHost" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
    <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2"
        width="100%" name="silverlight1" id="SLobj" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
        <param name="source" value="Sample.xap" />
        <param name="onerror" value="onSilverlightError" />
        <param name="background" value="white" />
        <param name="initparams" value="clientip=<%= Request.UserHostAddress %>, username=<%= HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name %>, StartupMode=HTML" />
        <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50401.0" />
        <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
        <param name="onLoad" value="SilverlightpluginLoaded" />
        <param name="culture" value="<%= System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name %>" />
        <param name="windowless" value="true" />
        <param name="uiculture" value="<%= System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name %>" />
        <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.50401.0" style="text-decoration: none;">
            <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=108181" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight"
                style="border-style: none" />
        </a>
    </object>
    <iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style='visibility: hidden; height: 0; width: 0; border: 0px'>
    </iframe>
</asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

try these

Clear floats. Add a div at the end of the table and set style as "clear:both"
For the iframe at the bottom of the page, remove the visibility: hidden style and add "display:none"

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to set Height and Width from silverlight Application.
Try to set Height and Width in Silverlight Application.
Like Set Page Property of bellow.

`VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"`

Answer (score 0):

Add Height=100% to the Object tag. Right now, it is setting only the width.